# GetClientRect is not giving the correct Rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I am trying to create an overlay form that overlays the contents of an external window (excluding the borders etc). I believe that `GetClientRect` is the correct winapi for that purpose however it does not seem to be working.

I created an example where I load up a form as a black box and display it over an open Notepad.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WinFormsApp2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Process? targetProc = null;

        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, ref Point lpPoint);

        public static Rectangle GetWindowRectangle(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            Point point = new Point();
            GetClientRect(hWnd, out RECT rect);
            ClientToScreen(hWnd, ref point);
            return new Rectangle(point.X, point.Y, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);
        }

        private IntPtr notepadhWnd;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.BackColor = Color.Black;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            targetProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p != null);

            try
            {
                if (targetProc != null)
                {
                    notepadhWnd = targetProc.MainWindowHandle;

                    if (notepadhWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        Rectangle rect = GetWindowRectangle(notepadhWnd);
                        Location = new Point(rect.Left, rect.Top);
                        Size = new Size(rect.Width, rect.Height);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log and message or
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The output of this is:
[image: Notepad being completely covered by form]

I expected the output to be:
[image: Only contents of Notepad being covered by form]

From all my searches I believe that the `GetClientRect` API should only return the client area but not sure what I am missing.

Comment: `GetClientRect` always returns coordinates relative to itself i.e. the top left is always 0,0. So subtracting those does not make a difference. It is also why `ClientToScreen` is required in order to map the coordinates to screen coords

Comment: Use [`GetWindowRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) instead to get a window's rectangle in screen coordinates

Comment: That reply was to someone who suggested to subtract the left and right coordinates to get the width of the rectangle to solve this. `GetWinodwRect` includes the non-client area, i.e. the window borders, caption bar etc. The question is why does `GetClientRect` also include them? I don't want `GetWindowRect` I want the client area of the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab coffee, this will be a long answer.

First, take a look at the image of notepad below.  From the wording of your question it sounds like you are expecting GetClientRect to return the area marked in red.  GetClientRect returns the dimensions of the window handle you provide *but* without the borders or scroll bars.  In other words, it will give you the interior area of the green rectangle.

[image: Notepad with markup]

There is no single "client window" - in the screenshot below the menu bar is a child window.  So is the status bar at the bottom of the screen.  So is the editor space which seems to be what you are interested in.

So, how do you get the hWnd of the editor space?  I'm not aware of any answer to that question that doesn't rely on the dark magic.  It is all fraught with peril... do you iterate through all the child windows and pick the biggest?  Pick a point in the dead center of the window and use API calls to find the hWnd at that location?  No matter what you do, it will not be an exact science.  For purposes of this question, though, I'll show one approach.

Every window has a Class name associated with it.  In the image below I'm using a tool called Spy++ to reveal information about the various windows.  As you can see, the window that makes up the editor space has a class name of "RichEditD2DPT"

[image]

I want to stress again how brittle this solution is.  You could have more than one child window of the given class.  The application developer could change to a different control with a different class name without warning.  Nevertheless, below is code to enumerate through the child windows until the desired class is found.  After that, I'm simply passing *that* hWnd into the code you already had and it seems to work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);
    private IntPtr _notepadMainhWnd;
    private IntPtr _notepadEditorhWnd;

    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, ref Point lpPoint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd, WindowEnumProc func, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

    private delegate bool WindowEnumProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam);

    public static Rectangle GetWindowRectangle(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        Point point = new Point();
        GetClientRect(hWnd, out RECT rect);
        bool ret = ClientToScreen(hWnd, ref point);
        Debug.WriteLine($"{point.X},{point.Y}");
        return new Rectangle(point.X, point.Y, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        var targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault(p => p != null);

        if (targetProcess != null)
        {
            // Get the main application window
            _notepadMainhWnd = targetProcess.MainWindowHandle;

            if (_notepadMainhWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // Looks for child windows having the class name "RichEditD2DPT"
                EnumChildWindows(_notepadMainhWnd, callback, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (_notepadEditorhWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = GetWindowRectangle(_notepadEditorhWnd);
                    Location = new Point(rect.Left, rect.Top);
                    Size = new Size(rect.Width, rect.Height);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool callback(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (GetClassName(hWnd, _buffer, _buffer.Capacity) != 0)
        {
            if (string.CompareOrdinal(_buffer.ToString(), "RichEditD2DPT") == 0)
            {
                _notepadEditorhWnd = hWnd;
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for the detailed response. that makes sense. I guess more so then the editor space what I am looking for is anyway to reliably exclude the top of the window i.e. the part with minimization maximisation etc. I thought `getClientWindow` was the way as other libraries like: https://github.com/SnosMe/electron-overlay-window seem to use that internally.

Comment: I want to make a generic overlay for any program but that excludes the titlebar / close controls etc. Would there not be a way to do that as given your answer it seems like programs can arbitrarily implement those in separate child windows.

Comment: If you are only concerned with the title bar look at this and see if it gets you closer... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-gettitlebarinfo

Comment: The green rectangle includes the window caption which is most definitely not part of the client area.

Comment: The updated image no longer explains the observed behavior (where the black rectangle covers the *entire* window area).

Comment: See this was my main confusion which I didn't articulate clearly i.e. why were both `GetClientWindow` and `GetWinodwRect` giving the same dimensions when at the very least the Titlebar should be excluded

Comment: @zecuria An answer should be accepted, if it answers the question. If it doesn't, then it shouldn't be the accepted answer. There is no obligation for an asker to accept a proposed answer. If anything, leaving a question without an accepted answer drives more traffic to it.